# Unreal Android Build Error: Required array size too large

Tags: android, game-development, unreal-engine5

We are trying to build an Android apk of the game. we have 33 items in the array for the build and have been getting the following error.

Build Error:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Execution failed for task ':app:buildDebugPreBundle'.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): > Required array size too large
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): * Try:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): BUILD FAILED in 1m 26s
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): > Task :app:buildDebugPreBundle FAILED
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): 59 actionable tasks: 59 executed
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): ERROR: cmd.exe failed with args /c "F:\METACRAFT UNREAL PROJECTS 2022\Vk_DESKTOP-5D1UG1M_200\Intermediate\Android\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:bundleDebug
```

When we remove all the items and just add 1 item (level) it builds perfectly fine. Please suggest whats the best way to resolve it?